# C# winforms toolbar buttons

Tags: c#, winforms, toolbar

I got an application that the main form contains a System.Windows.Forms.ToolBar.
I want to add a new System.Windows.Forms.ToolBarButton with a little longer text from the rest. so on the designer window when I press Enter after I changed the text, I see part of it with 3 dots (...) and when I click OK, the toolbar itself gets very wide for some reason and the spaced between every item gets bigger.
I couldn't find a lot online about this control... maybe it's old but I can't change it.
I tried to access the buttons but when I drag, the whole toolar mooves.
What can I do ?
Thank you very much !!

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of some description?

Comment: Are you in a position to upgrade or change this form?  The Toolbar control is an older control that has since been replaced by the Toolstrip control, which gives you much more flexibility.